# Are prisoners of war paid by their captors today?

Tags: rules-of-war, geneva-convention

The [Third Geneva Convention](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/applic/ihl/ihl.nsf/Article.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=20A27E4768ED47CBC12563CD0051AF68) calls for all POWs to receive a monthly allowance from their captors, separate from anything they may be paid for working while imprisoned, “to enable prisoners to improve their lot during captivity, but subject to reimbursement by” their own country. ([1960 commentary](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/applic/ihl/ihl.nsf/Comment.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=C671C3ABFE331532C12563CD00427137))

A parenthetical remark in Tolstoy’s 1869 novel *War and Peace* that a Russian character captured by the French in 1812 “received the allowance of three rubles a week made to officers” (Part 13, Chapter 12) suggests that this was a practice that long predated the Geneva Conventions. Therefore conflicts and detainees to which the Geneva Conventions might not apply are still within the scope of this question.

**Are POWs paid by their captors today?** If so, by which countries? If not, when and why did it stop?
Every time I try to google this, I find only results for whether POWs accumulate pay due them from their *own* country.

Comment: I would suggest looking for War Crime allegations related to treatment of prisoners of War.  The Geneva convention does have an exception for allowances and even provisions when the captor's nation is having trouble feeding it's own troops and civilians, which is a common problem in war, even when your side is winning.

Comment: Are there openly acknowledged wars today where there would be POW within the Geneva convention ?

Comment: @Max I don't know, but since this practice occurred long before the conventions, it could conceivably occur today outside where the conventions apply, either in non-signatory countries, or in unacknowledged wars.

Comment: You can be pretty sure it doesn't apply to "enemy combatants".

Comment: The last instance when country said the Convention applied was Pakistan with the Indian pilot they captured [last spring](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/defence/iaf-pilot-in-pak-custody-will-be-governed-under-geneva-convention-pakistani-army/articleshow/68188757.cms). But I don't know if they paid him anything since his stay was not that long.

Comment: @Max sorry for resurrecting an old comment; but for the sake of clarity of future readers, Geneva convention on prisoners of war applies not only to declared wars but to all armed conflict between signatories, even explicitly stating in Article 2 "even if the state of war is not recognized by one of them" and also to occupying others' territory without armed resistance; so the convention is relevant no matter if wars are acknowledged or not.